# Appending to yield in content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say I have this helper in `application_helper.rb`

```
def my_helper(content = nil, *args, &block)
   content_tag(:div, class: :my_wrapper) do
      (block_given? ? yield : content) + content_tag(:span, "this is the end", *args)
   end
end
```

And i call it from a view with

```
my_helper do 
  content_tag(:div, "this is the beginning")
end
```

I would expect the result to be something like

```
<div class="my_wrapper">
    <div>
       this it the beginning
    </div>
    <span>
       this is the end
    </span>
</div>
```

But in fact, the span with the text "this is the end" will not be appended to the yield.

If i were to use this line in the helper instead:

```
(block_given? ? content_tag(:div, &block) : content) + content_tag(:span, "this is the end", *args)
```

I would get both content, but the yield would be wrapped inside another div.

How could I add / append content after a yield, without wrapping the yield in a different content_tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`capture`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture) to achieve this:

```
def my_helper(content = nil, *args, &block)
  content_tag(:div, class: :my_wrapper) do
    (block_given? ? capture(&block) : content) + content_tag(:span, "this is the end", *args)
  end
end
```

And be sure to do this in your view:

```
<%= my_helper do %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, "this is the beginning") %>
<%- end %>
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks. What does yield really do? I guess capture makes it a string instead?

Comment: `yield` does the same as `block.call` in this example, it executes a given block, and then it yields the resulting return value. `capture` returns what is being rendered inside the block so you can store it in a variable or do something with it.